# Units and missing constants in quintessence expressions?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, potential, units, cosmological-inflation

In cosmology, quintessence is an alternative to the cosmological constant. In this approach (described [here](http://energy.nobelprize.org/presentations/linde.pdf)), we consider a scalar field $\phi$ and its self-interacting potential $V\left(\phi\right)$ statisfying the Klein-Gordon equation:

$$\ddot{\phi}+3H\dot{\phi}+\frac{dV\left(\phi\right)}{d\phi} = 0$$

and with a pressure $P=\frac{\dot{\phi}^2}{2}-V\left(\phi\right)$ and an energy density $\rho_{E}=\rho c^2=\frac{\dot{\phi}^2}{2}+V\left(\phi\right)$. As always, particle physicists completely ignore $c$ and $h$ constants which is not very practical when one wants to implement these equations.

My question is pretty simple: what are the units in SI system of $\phi$ and $V\left(\phi\right)$ and what are the expressions of the Klein-Gordon equation, the pressure $P$ and the density $\rho_{E}$ with all the necessary physical constants?

Comment: I disagree with the notion that c & h are neglected. What actually happens is a unit system in which c=h=1 is chosen instead.

Comment: You can always re-put $c$ and $h$ with the right exponents in your equations once you know the unit of measurement of the terms. And there is always only one way to put  $c$ and $h$ with the right exponents.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I agree, they are not neglected, the equation is juste in natural units.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin: this is what they say. But my personal experience with some particle physicist is that they have a hard time when a numerical physicist come to ask them the units of the quantity they are manipulating... (and the simple fact that this question has not been answered yet suggest that this is not that simple)

Comment: Why would you want units anyway? I mean, there's a *reason* that natural units are used. And if you're a numerical physicist, you should know that scaled units are far easier to work with computationally than physical units (due to floating point precision).

Comment: @KyleKanos: well spotted. First, personnally, if I do not know the physical dimensions of the quantities I am manipulating I consider that there is a problem. Second, if you are scaling everything in the same manner, it does not change the precision since your floating point numbers are still represented by a mantissa and an exponent (and in double precision you can go up to 10^308 before starting to have problems...)

Comment: I work with hydrodynamics, so not everything is scaled by the same constant. Is your field $\phi$, potential $V(\phi)$ and scale factor $H$ all scaled with the same constant? If yes, then fp doesn't matter; if no, then fp does matter & scaled units are what you want.

Comment: Well, why not compile a list of the Planck units of the desired quantities? Then what you do is you divide the energies (e.g. the potential V) by the Planck energy, the pressure by the Planck unit for pressure etc. etc. G, c, and hbar are set equal to 1 anyway, so you are only dividing by 1, therefore you are not changing anything. However, the resulting formal expression in terms of hbar, c and G is the correct SI expression.